# Parsing date format "2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z" with JSON in GoLang

Tags: json, date, go

I am receiving the following date format from an API (Jira) and I need to unmarshal it with json. I've tried a custom unmarshal method but it can't parse the date and doesn't say why.

"2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z"

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

const ctLayout = "2021-02-04T08:18:40.812-0600"
const ctLayoutWithZ = "2021-02-04T08:18:40.812Z"

// Implement Marshaler and Unmarshaler interface
func (j *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    t, err := time.Parse(ctLayout, s)
    if err != nil {
        t, err = time.Parse(ctLayoutWithZ, s)

        if (err != nil) {
            return err
        }
    }
    j.Time = t
    return nil
}
    
func (j CustomTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(j)
}
```

EDIT  I think it is actually this date that won't parse: 2021-03-23T14:31:27.672-0500

Answer (score 4):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   b := []byte(`{"date": "2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z"}`)
   var s struct { Date time.Time }
   json.Unmarshal(b, &s)
   // {Date:2020-10-21 05:00:57.258 +0000 UTC}
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the layout needs to be a representation of this specific date:
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
according to https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

In your case, for ISO 8601 the layout would be:
2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the case. Since the parse func is defined as `func Parse(layout, value string) (Time, error)` the first argument needs to be the format of the date which has specific values in go, and for `"2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z"` it needs to be `2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z`. It will give a bit cryptic error indeed `panic: parsing time "2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z" as "2021-02-04T08:18:40.812Z": cannot parse "-10-21T05:00:57.258Z" as "1"`, but once you switch the `ctLayout` to `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"` it will parse it fine https://play.golang.org/p/80PYBoe-YJD

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`time.RFC3339`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) as a layout like this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := "2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z"
    parsed, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, a)
    fmt.Println(parsed)
    // Output: 2020-10-21 05:00:57.258 +0000 UTC
}
```

[Demo: Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lDBQ30poAHG)

Answer (score -1):

standart package `time` implements interface `json.Unmarshaler` by default: [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON)

all you need is:

```
func main() {
    foo := struct {
        Time time.Time `json:"time"` // dont forget about json tag
    }{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"time": "2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z"}`), &foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(foo.Time)
}
```

output:

```
2020-10-21 05:00:57.258 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: "2020-10-21T05:00:57.258Z" format is time.RFC3339